# Ошибка в SQL-запросе при работе с Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Полгода назад написал пробный код для работы с Hibernate, который однозначно работал. На днях решил вернуться к доработке кода, но при выборке данных теперь появляется ошибка:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL  
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

Я взял сгенерированый запрос из лога ошибки:

```sql
select r1_0.id,
       a1_0.id,
       a1_0.alias,
       a1_0.name,
       r1_0.description,
       r1_0.name
from rules as r1_0
         left outer join (accessors as a1_0) on r1_0.id = a1_0.parent_id
```

И попробовал его выполнить непосредственно в SQL, что привело к такой же ошибке:

```
[2019-08-24 17:22:10] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
[2019-08-24 17:22:10] Position: 181
```

Я попробовал убрать скобочки из запроса и он выполнился без ошибок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть причиной появления данной ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

[Нет там](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L11825) по [синтаксису](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L11955) скобок для имени одной таблицы. Для дополнительного выражения join - есть, например для:

```
select * from t1 left outer join (t2 join t3 on condition) as f on condition
```

А для

```
join (accessors as a1_0)
```

Это недопустимый синтаксис. И в далёком прошлом например postgresql 7.4 грамматика выглядит так же и в обозримом будущем для postgresql 13.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что запрос неправильный, но он в таком виде генерируется hibernate и я пока не знаю как это исправить.Больше всего смущает, что этот код однозначно работал раньше и никаких исправлений в него я не вносил

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. код не менялся, я предположил, что изменения могли произойти в самой библиотеке **hibernate-core**. Как я и предполагал, в апреле вышла версия 6.0 и т.к. по-умолчанию в pom.xml было указан ключ *LATEST*, то подтягивалась именно она. После указания использовать актуальную библиотеку версии 5.4 ошибка пропала.